# методы ооп python

Tags: python

Скажите, как в Python называются такие конструкции и что они делают?
`list.__init __(self)` и `list.__getitem__`

```
class A(list):
    def __init__(self, start):
        list.__init__(self) # что здесь происходит?
        self.start= start
 
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return list.__getitem__(self, item) # что здесь происходит?
        except IndexError:
            return self.start
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @dIm0n я не спрашивал что такое классы, я спрашивал конкретно про конструкцию list.__init __(self). Что эта строка делает в этом коде? Как это называется, чтобы можно было посмотреть в инете?

Comment: __init__(self) - конструктор класса
https://younglinux.info/oopython/init.php

Comment: 1) переходите по ссылке 2) нажимаете ctrl+F или другой биндинг для поиска в браузере 3) вводите `__init__`

Comment: list.__getitem__(self, item) Зачем мы тут пишем __ getitem __, если можно просто написать return self.list[item]?

Comment: Специально перешел по ссылке и посмотрел. Вы сами то смотрели, что Вы человеку предлагаете?  Там нет ни одного похожего примера и объяснения

Comment: @RomanR никто не говорил, что там будет похожий пример (определите метрику похожести для начала), но объяснение, что это такое, и название конструкции там есть, что и спрашивается в вопросе

Comment: Это вызов родительского метода. Класс А наследуется от list, и вызывает родительские методы из переопределённых

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
list.__init__(self) # что здесь происходит?
```

Вызывается конструктор класса `list`, который является родителем. Но обычно это делают так:

```py
super().__init__()
```

Конструктор принимает аргумент `self`, указывающий на объект, который мы хотим инициализировать. В вызове `list.__init__(self)` мы говорим, что хотим инициализировать текущий объект (класса `A`) конструктором класса `list`.

---

```py
return list.__getitem__(self, item) # что здесь происходит?
```

Здесь автор хотел "достучаться" до метода `__getitem__` класса `list` и попытаться вызвать его для объекта класса `A`. В случае неудачи (`IndexError`) вернуть какое-то дефолтное значение `self.start`.

> `list.__getitem__(self, item)` Зачем мы тут пишем `__getitem__`, если можно просто написать `return self.list[item]`?

Почему пишем `__getitem__` - объяснил выше. Просто написать `return self.list[item]` нельзя, потому что экземпляр класса `A` не содержит атрибута с именем `list` (нигде не было `self.list = ...`). Если написать так, то это приведёт к `AttributeError`.

Здесь так же можно было (потому что наследуемся от `list`) написать:

```py
super().__getitem__(item)
```

Но автор кода, почему-то, захотел так.

Comment: @vp_arth там не self.list, а self.start. Опечатался